# Does it work to have the same Username on workstation and server

Tags: windows-7, domain, windows-sbs-2008, user-accounts

I am relatively new to networking. We have about 40 computers on a network and one SBS 2008. We want to use the SBS for file and print sharing, but would prefer not to go to a domain situation. Unless perhaps there's a way to keep profiles local and just use the domain to "sync" users.

My question is if you have a user on workstation: computer15/username can I just create that user on the server (servercomputer/username) and give it permissions for a shared folder? What I've read online suggests that is possible. Seems like you could end up accidentally sharing to a same-named user you don't want to.

I'm open to suggestions of a better way to go. We inherited a broken system and have just gotten rid of the Domain / Active Directory system to get things up and running.

Comment: Perhaps I muddled the issue: can anyone tell me if you have identical username on a workstation and Win SBS 2008 and give permissions to that user, should you be able to access those resources across the network? Or is the computer in effect part of the user name?

Comment: We may go back to the domain and I appreciate the suggestions to that effect. I would like a definitive answer to my question.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would migrate to SBS by joining the computers to the domain as it's going to make long term management a heck of a lot easier. The wizard that's used to join a computer to an SBS based domain includes functionallity to map the local user profile to the domain user profile, so that should simplify the task of getting the two "in sync".

Comment: +1 Way more simple to have Active Directory and profiles can remain local to the workstation.

Comment: the network was somewhat slow and flaky, causing computers on the AD to have sometimes two minute startup time and the main business software (which is itself flaky) to crash regularly. We were spending about 30% our time just troubleshooting domain caused weirdness.

Comment: also our replacement to the business software is likely to be webbased rather than access/mssql based and we may well end up with a linux system serving that. We have no real need for the profiles to be on a server -there are very few user documents to be backed up.